# На ноутбуке не прокручивается веб-страница

Tags: html, css, background

На мониторе 24 дюйма вся страница помещается целиком, на ноутбуке 15 дюймов 1366х768 не прокручивается вниз. Как исправить?

```css
.container-global {
    background: url("https://www.desktopbackground.org/download/o/2013/05/19/578484_mountain-lake-wallpapers_1366x768_h.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container-global::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .73);
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 1059px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: AdobeInvisFont, Courier, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
}

.header {
    margin-top: 141px;
}

.logo-float {
    float: left;
}

.logo-float::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.email-phone {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.logo-text {
    float: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}


.logo-text span:first-child {
    font-size: 26px;
}

.logo-text span:last-child {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.email-phone span:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.header-float::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.tours-float-1 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 48px;
}

.card-1, .card-2, .card-3, .card-4, .card-5, .card-6 {
    float: left;
}

.desc {
    margin-top: 22px;
    text-align: center;
}

.tours-float-2 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 58px;
}

.tours-float-1::after, .tours-float-2::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.card-1, .card-4 {
    margin-right: 34px;
}

.card-2, .card-5 {
    margin: 0 34px 0 34px;
}

.card-3, .card-6 {
    margin-left: 34px;
}

.footer {
    margin: 61px 0 20px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-global">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header-float">
                <div class="logo-float">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="http://www.wowpinoy.ca/_icon/insurance.png" alt="Logo"></div>
                    <div class="logo-text"><span>Lorem</span><br><span>Ipsum</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="email-phone"><span>tours@milanoholidays.com</span><br><span>+39 338 709 0880</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="tours">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="tours-float-1">
                <div class="card-1">
                    <div class="img-box"><img src="https://avto-tourizm.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bitmap_6.png" alt="Shopping Tours"></div>
                    <div class="desc"><span>Shopping Tours</span></div></div>
                <div class="card-2">
                    <div class="img-box"><img src="https://avto-tourizm.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bitmap_6.png" alt="Sightseeing Tours"></div>
                    <div class="desc"><span>Sightseeing Tours</span></div></div>
                <div class="card-3">
                    <div class="img-box"><img src="https://avto-tourizm.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bitmap_6.png" alt="Food Tours"></div>
                    <div class="desc"><span>Food Tours</span></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tours-float-2">
                <div class="card-4">
                    <div class="img-box"><img src="https://avto-tourizm.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bitmap_6.png" alt="Bars & Nightlife"></div>
                    <div class="desc"><span>Bars & Nightlife</span></div></div>
                <div class="card-5">
                    <div class="img-box"><img src="https://avto-tourizm.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bitmap_6.png" alt="Art & Architecture"></div>
                    <div class="desc"><span>Art & Architecture</span></div></div>
                <div class="card-6">
                    <div class="img-box"><img src="https://avto-tourizm.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bitmap_6.png" alt="Walking Tours"></div>
                    <div class="desc"><span>Walking Tours</span></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="copyright">&copy; 2018 Copyright Milan Holidays, Inc. All rights reserved.</div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[То же самое на codepen](https://codepen.io/Black_Fire/pen/poJNrdo)

Comment: убрать overflow: hidden;

Comment: в этом случае сверху появляется отступ

Comment: Проверил здесь и на codepen — отступ сверху не появляется.

Comment: проверил только что, появляется

Comment: Допустим, поверю вам на слово, тогда замените margin-top на padding-top, чтобы не появлялся

Comment: @MaximLensky зачем, если флоаты тоже неплохо работают?

Comment: @MaximLensky,  MaximLensky, andreymal Не спится? )))

Comment: @MaximLensky Согласен, сон для слабых )))

Comment: @MaximLensky Давай )

Answer (score 0):

*Это пример на flex :*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://www.desktopbackground.org/download/o/2013/05/19/578484_mountain-lake-wallpapers_1366x768_h.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.desc {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">
        lorem <br> ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        tours@milanoholidays.com<br> +39 338 709 0880
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x140" alt="">
        <div class="desc">какое то описание</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x140" alt="">
        <div class="desc">какое то описание</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x140" alt="">
        <div class="desc">какое то описание</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x140" alt="">
        <div class="desc">какое то описание</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x140" alt="">
        <div class="desc">какое то описание</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x140" alt="">
        <div class="desc">какое то описание</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>
    all right reserved <a href="#">powered by lensky</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

*Это переделанный пример на float:*

```css
.clear,
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://www.desktopbackground.org/download/o/2013/05/19/578484_mountain-lake-wallpapers_1366x768_h.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.right,
.left,
.center {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.one {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container clear one">
      <div class="left">
        lorem <br> ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        tours@milanoholidays.com <br> +39 338 709 0880
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container clear">
      <div class="left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
        <p>lore ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container clear">
      <div class="left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
        <p>lore ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>all right reserved <a href="#">powered by author</a> </p>
</div>
```

**Хотя и там  и там при правильном применении ни каких косяков не происходит**

**Оба примера смотреть на полный экран так как не писал медиа запросы**

*Адаптивный пример на трёх колоночного макета наfloat :*

```css
.clear,
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


.container {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 980px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.center {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 30%);
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.left a {
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 0;
  text-align-last: left;
}

@media (max-width: 880px) {
  .center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 50%);
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 645px) {
  .center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 60%);
    margin-top: -10px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 445px) {
  .center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 70%);
    margin-top: -10px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container clear">
    <div class="left">
      <a href="#">home</a>
      <a href="#">about</a>
      <a href="#">portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">work</a>
      <a href="#">mail</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="center">
     <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum non perferendis vel nemo placeat officiis. Et magni illum repellat doloremque laudantium illo laboriosam? Minima veniam, quod et maiores magnam ut!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>
      all right reserved <a href="#">creaded by Stidio Lensky</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```